# Pass in JSON input to DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

```
...
// result is a JSON data passed to this function from outside
var result = getMyJSON();
var input = "{aaData: ["+result+"],"+'aoColumns':[
    { 'sTitle': 'Title', 'mDataProp': 'title' }]}";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable(input);
});
</script>

<table id='example' class='example' border='1'>
```

I know that .dataTable() function expects initialization object as specified here: http://datatables.net/ref#aaData
If inside the dataTable function I manually paste the JSON data - then it displays everything fine. How can I "prepare" and pass in as an initialization object to dataTables() function? Right now this is not working as it should.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are building your input var as a string - it is an object. Try this instead

```
var input = {
    "aaData" : [result],
    "aoColumns" : [{
        "sTitle" : "Title"
    }, {
        "mDataProp" : "title"
    }]
};
```

Comment: What if I don't want to specify **aoColumns** attribute. I want to prepare my table's header with few conditions. So I cannot go with it. Will that allow to give a proper table?